# JQuery Tools - Validator - Validate without submit button

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I hope somebody can help.

I have been using JQuery Tools to validate my forms without issue but now need to process a form programmatically.

The following 2 lines validate the form however I am not sure how to return a success/fail value once the check has happened.

```
var check = $("#new_form :input").validator();
check.data("validator").checkValidity();
```

Essentially I am thinking (rightly or wrongly?) along these lines:-

```
var check = $("#new_form :input").validator();
check.data("validator").checkValidity();
if (check==true) {........

.....}
```

Hopefully the above makes sense.  I have studied the [Validator Usage page](http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/index.html) and tried to crack it by myself but no joy.

Help and suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: That *should* work, are you having any problems/errors using this method?

Comment: Thanks Christian - Just solved it and yes it was working of sorts.  I used if (check.data("validator").checkValidity()==true){...}

Comment: @user680177: if you solve the problem yourself then the usual process is to put the solution you used down as an answer that you can then mark as correct. This is preferable to putting "[solved]" in the subject and makes it easier for anybody with a similar problem to very easily see what the solution was.

Comment: @Chris Don't edit the title with "solved", approved your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it in the end

```
if (check.data("validator").checkValidity()==true){...}
```